# Any way to decipher Four Tet's "About" page on Spotify?

Tags: meaning, electronic-music

The electronic music artist Kieran Hebdan, better known by his stage name [Four Tet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Tet), has an interesting [*About*](https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Eu1txygG6nJttLHbZdQOh?si=__pxR1_9TEiXJ7WHbPKSZQ) page on Spotify. It looks to me to be just gibberish, but perhaps there is some way to decipher its meaning?

Below is what I get when I copy and paste the biography portion.

> **Biography**
>
> ̟̞̝̜̙̘̗̖҉̵̴̨̧̢̡̼̻̺̹̳̲̱̰̯̮̭̬̫̪̩̦̥̤̣̠҈͈͇͉͍͎͓͔͕͖͙͚͜͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢͢ͅ 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　⦁ 　　　　　　　　　　　　 ⦁ 　　　　　　　　　　　⦁ 　　 　　　　　　　　　⚫ 　　　　　　　　⦁ 　　　　　　. 　　　　 ⚫ 　　　 ⦁ 　 　　☀️
> ༼༭ຶཬɷԾㅍ◟ㅍ)აِّّْٕٔٓٓ ˓˚✧₊⁎❝᷀ົཽ*ೃ:(꒡͡  ❝᷀ົཽ ꉺლ༽༼இ•̛)ྀ◞ ༎ຶ ༽ৣৢ؞ৢ؞ؖ ཥ•̫͡•ཤꉺ༽♡(•ི̛ᴗ͇ˊ̑⁾ ἴृ ⁽(༽۩۪؞ءؙۜؖۛ ّّٕٓٔٓٙٓ͡༼Ծɷ༼(⁽*(ू•‧̫இ ꒡
> 　°。 *¸.·* ´¨・*・

Comment: It looks a little bit to me like what sheet music looks like if printed in the wrong font. You might try rendering it in a musical font like Sonata.

Comment: ⣎⡇ꉺლ༽இ•̛)ྀ◞ ༎ຶ ༽ৣৢ؞ৢ؞ؖ ꉺლ is one of his aliases: https://00000ooooo.bandcamp.com/

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica There are certainly multiple fonts there. For instance, இ is from the [Tamil alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script#Vowels) and represents a short "i" sound, as in "hit", and ɷ is the [Latin small letter closed omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega#Latin/IPA_omega). It's most likely gibberish.